# Sidekiq Worker: Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'ip-address' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, redis, sidekiq, sidetiq

I have a Sidekiq worker scheduled everyday at 1200 hours using Sidetiq's recurrence option and when this worker starts, I always end up with the worker connecting to the wrong address to connect to wrong database server whose IP is not present in my `config/database.yml`.

The correct url is to connect to `mysqluser:mysql-database-ip` but it connects to `mysqluser:ip-address`

Below are the configurations for the files. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

**database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database2connect
  username: mysqluser
  password: <%= ENV['mysql_password'] %>
  host: mysql-database-ip
  pool: 25
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Sidekiq Initializer file**

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://:#{ENV['redis_password']}@localhost:96526" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://:#{ENV['redis_password']}@localhost:96526" }
end
```

**Sidekiq YML file**

```
:verbose: true
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid

production:
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log

development:
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq.dev.log

:concurrency:  5
```

**Sidekiq Worker**

```
class MySidekiqWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  sidekiq_options({
                      # Should be set to true (enables uniqueness for async jobs)
                      # or :all (enables uniqueness for both async and scheduled jobs)
                      unique: :all,
                      retry: 5,
                      raise_error: true
                  })

  recurrence backfill: true do
    daily.hour_of_day(12)
  end

  def perform(last_occurrence, current_occurrence)
    billing_cycle_users = MySQLTable.where("parameter_1 <= ? AND parameter_1 >= ?", param1, param2) #Fails here!!!!

  end
end
```

**Error Log**

```
"class"=>"MySidekiqWorker", "args"=>[1458129600.0, 1458199815], "retry"=>5, "queue"=>"default", "unique"=>"all", "raise_error"=>true, "jid"=>"bb2bce00baff05439c997a4e", "created_at"=>1458199815.0152047, "enqueued_at"=>1458200862.463864, "error_message"=>"Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'ip-address' (using password: NO)", "error_class"=>"Mysql2::Error", "failed_at"=>1458199815.076714, "retry_count"=>5, "retried_at"=>1458200862.4711788}
2016-03-17T07:47:42.472Z 3427 TID-djcl0 WARN: Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'ip-address' (using password: NO)
2016-03-17T07:47:42.472Z 3427 TID-djcl0 WARN: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:128:in `replace_bind_variables'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:115:in `sanitize_sql_array'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:26:in `sanitize_sql_for_conditions'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:899:in `build_where'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:545:in `where!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:535:in `where'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in `where'
/home/project/app/workers/my_sidekiq_worker.rb:17:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:151:in `execute_job'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-middleware-0.3.0/lib/sidekiq-middleware/server/unique_jobs.rb:11:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidetiq-0.7.0/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:18:in `call_with_sidetiq_history'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidetiq-0.7.0/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:6:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:31:in `with_context'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `block in process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:167:in `stats'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:79:in `process_one'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:67:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Only works if I do the below config in my `sidekiq.rb` initializer file! But doesnt' sidekiq pick it up from `database.yml`?

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://:#{ENV['redis_password']}@localhost:96526" }
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    { :adapter => 'mysql2',
       :database => ' database2connect',
       :host => 'mysql-database-ip',
       :username => 'mysqluser',
       :password => 'somepassword' }
  )
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://:#{ENV['redis_password']}@localhost:96526" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease kill and restart sidekiq.
It works for me.